# Стек на C# на основе массива

Tags: c#, стек

Всем привет!

Попробовал сделать пример стека из книжки "Полный справочник на  С#" Г. Шилдта.
Но почему-то не работает, может, кто поможет понять, почему.

В Метода stk.full выдает ошибку в  `return t==stk.Length`, якобы "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта".

Где моя ошибка?)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
   {
    class Stek{
       char[] stk;
        int t;

        public Stek(int size){
            char[] stk=new char[size];
            t=0;
            Console.WriteLine("создание объект");
        }
        // Добавляем в стек элемент
        public void setStk(char element)
        {

            if (t == stk.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Опасность!!! Стек Перегружен!!!");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("s2");
            stk[t] = (char)element;
            t++;

        }
        // извлекаем из стека элемент
        public char getStk()
        {
           // char element;
            if (t == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Стек Пуст!!!!");
                return (char)0;
             }

            t--;
            return stk[t];
        }
        // Размер Стека
        public bool full()
        {
            return t==stk.Length;
        }                  
            }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size = 10;
            Stek s = new Stek(size);

            Console.WriteLine("Помещаем Элементы в Стек!!!!!");

        for (int i = 1;!s.full(); i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" " + i);
            s.setStk((char)i);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Извлекаем Элементы из Стека!!!!!");
        while  (!s.full()){
        Console.WriteLine(s.getStk()+" ");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в методе **full**  обращаетесь к полю **stk**, а это поле у вас не инициализировано. Вы, вероятно, хотели инициализировать его в конструкторе:

```
public Stek(int size)
{
    char[] stk = new char[size];
    t = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("создание объект");
}
```

но на самом деле вместо инициализации поля **stk** вы создаете новый, совершенно не относящийся к нему массив инструкцией

```
char[] stk = new char[size];
```

если хотите инициализировать именно поле класса, то вместо char[] stk = new char[size] пишите stk = new char[size];

Кстати, помимо этой ошибки проблем у вас в коде очень много

Comment:  спасибо, все помогло)